# Error executing query with parameters in golang with mysql driver

Tags: jquery, mysql, go

I created a func that execute query on mysql database.
I use this package "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

but if I run this:

```
...
err := database.ExecuteSql("INSERT INTO xxx(field1, field2, field3) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", "field1", 123, time.Now())
...
func ExecuteSql(cmd string, , args ...interface{}) error {
  ctx := context.Background()
  _, err := db.ExecContext(ctx, cmd, args)
  ctx.Done()
  ...
}
```

it returns me "sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type []interface {}, a slice of interface"

Comment: did you try `_, err := db.ExecContext(ctx, cmd, args...)`?

Comment: You're right!!! thanks, post it and I will flag as correct!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute the method like this:

```
_, err := db.ExecContext(ctx, cmd, args)
```

you pass `args` as only one `[]interface{}` argument. Slices are not supported as arguments for `ExecContext` method, unless its `[]byte`.

You need to use the unpack operator with `args`:

```
_, err := db.ExecContext(ctx, cmd, args...)
```